# SSL Error in adaptive paypal Preapproval API in Sandbox mod

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have used  Sandbox App credentials
APIUsername
APIPassword
APISignature

Error is coming in curl APi:-

```
Verbose information:

* Adding handle: conn: 0x37c7ef8
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x37c7ef8) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to svcs.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.0.82.89...
* Connected to svcs.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.89) port 443 (#0)
* error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
```

My question is can i use adaptive paypal API's without SSL

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal are removing support for TLS v1.0 and v1.1 this year. It won't be rolled out to production until June 2016 but is now live on Sandbox.

You'll need to update curl to at least version 7.34 to get TLS v1.2 support.

Sources:

https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update#php

https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/